# argparse choose a default append argument

Tags: python, argparse

**tl;dr** I can pass `prog.py a b -opt 1` and `prog.py -opt 1 a b`.  I cannot pass `prog.py a -opt 1 b`. I would like to.

Given an `ArgumentParser` setup like

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(dest='arg', action='append', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('-opt', dest='opt', action='store')
```

I want arguments to by-default be appended to `arg`

```
prog.py a -opt 1 b
```

I would like this to return argument tuple `(arg=[['a', 'b']], opt='1')`. But passing arguments with intermixed options will fail with error message `error: unrecognized arguments: b`.

However, passing arguments in this order succeeds:

```
prog.py a b -opt 1
prog.py -opt 1 a b
```

I cannot intermix the position of the arguments intended for `arg`.

How can I have the `ArgumentParser` fallback to appending to one argument parameter?

Comment: This seems confusing. Why wouldn't you keep your arguments in order?

Comment: A positional argument can be used once.  In aappend action doesn't make sense with a positional (unless is shares dest with another.

Comment: Newer versions have an `intermixed` parser that might so what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`argparse.parse_intermixed_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_intermixed_args).

Thanks [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj).